# Orleans two way communication between grain client and grain

Tags: orleans

I would like to implement a callback to a grain client inside a grain method Eg. during evaluation of Grain.Method1 a client method needs to be called to get some data.

I've tried to do so with streams, but when I subscribe the stream on client, the method does not fire.

Grain:

```
var config = ClusterConfiguration.LocalhostPrimarySilo();
config.AddMemoryStorageProvider();
config.Globals.RegisterStorageProvider<MemoryStorage>("PubSubStore");
config.Globals.RegisterStreamProvider<SimpleMessageStreamProvider>("MySMSProvider");
...
public override async Task OnActivateAsync() {
var streamProvider  = GetStreamProvider("MySMSProvider");
var stream = streamProvider.GetStream<MyTypeMessage>(myGuid, "MyStream");

RegisterTimer(s => {
   return stream.OnNextAsync(new MyTypeMessage());
}, null, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
...
```

Client:

```
var clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.LocalhostSilo();
clientConfiguration.RegisterStreamProvider<SimpleMessageStreamProvider>("MySMSProvider");
GrainClient.Initialize(clientConfiguration);
...
var streamProvider = GrainClient.GetStreamProvider("MySMSProvider");
var stream = requestStreamProvider.GetStream<MyTypeMessage>(myGuid, "MyStream");
await stream.SubscribeAsync(
            async (message, token) => { process message that does not fire });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are not keeping the reference to `StreamSubscriptionHandle<MyTypeMessage>` which is returned by subscription

Try something like this :

`var subscriptionHandle = await _factCalculationRequestStream
    .SubscribeAsync(async (message, token) => { process message that does not fire });`

and keep the `subscriptionHandle` from being garbage collected

In my case I ended up implementing `IGrainObserver` on my class (which is a websocketBehaviour in a WebAPI project and this subscription works well:

```
public class MySocketService: WebSocketBehavior, IGrainObserver, IDisposable
{
  private StreamSubscriptionHandle<MyStreamEvent>
  ...

  //inside some method invoked externally
  _streamSubscriberHandle = await requestedStream
     .SubscribeAsync(onStreamMessage, onStreamError, onStreamComplete);
}
```

Comment: I've also needed to add [Serializable] attribute to MyTypeMessage but now it works. Thank you.

Comment: Yes all input\output objects for any grain interface signatures must be marked as [Serializable]. We even wrote some tests for this :)